# Is there a shortcut to move tabs within the same group in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I haven't been able to find a shortcut to move the active tab within the same group (not into an other group), which would allow to change the order of the tabs in that group.

Comment: Look at `Move Editor Left` and `Move Editor Right` commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move Editor Left:    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>

Move Editor Right:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>

Comment: That works thank you! I changed the keybinds since i'm on laptop and PageUp/PageDown isn't practical here.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux is:

- Move Editor left `Alt`+`Super`+`LeftArrow`
- Move editor right `Alt`+`Super`+`RightArrow`

---

Just for completeness the command is called:
`View: Move Editor Left - workbench.action.moveEditorLeftInGroup`

You can modify it from the **Keyboard Shortcuts** menu.