# VS Code: rearrange tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Say I have a few tabs open in VS Code. How do I move my current tab left or right relative to its current position. I believe the Atom text editor had a shortcut for this (alt+shift+left/right) but that doesn't seem to work in VS Code.

Comment: All related actions can be found in the keyboard and shortcuts pane under `workbench.action.editor` - although the functionality you are after, does not exist, yet.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70669201/836330 There are built-in commands to move the current editor left or right.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is yet to be developed.
You can find the dev discussion thread here
[Commands to move tabs to desired position](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/8234)

Comment: That link is for an api to move tabs from within an extension.  Which as the issue explains, can be done.  This SO question isn't about an extension api in any case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I use these options:

workbench.action.moveEditorRightInGroup

workbench.action.moveEditorLeftInGroup

My VSCode version is 1.73.0. I remapped the hotkeys to what's in the screenshot as the only conflicting shortcuts for me were indent/outdent. I just use Tab/Shift+Tab for that.

[image: screenshot of vscode keyboard shortcut options for moving a tab right or left]